# Dynamically grab a specific column from a joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-columns

I have a very complex query pulling data from almost 10 tables already and growing, and I need to achieve something unusual. The main table (the `FROM` table) has a field named `SIZEPOS`, which is an index number from 1 to 25. A joined table with alias `siz` has the appropriate joining field (some foreign ID) to the main table, and also fields, like `SIZE1`, `SIZE2`, ..., `SIZE25`, where each of them holds a size value, ie `SIZE1` may hold the value 6, `SIZE2` value 8, etc...
So what I want is to include in my query the specific `SIZE+[SIZEPOS]` field of that joined table. In other words, if `SIZEPOS` holds the value 3 for a specific product, I want to grab the field `siz.SIZE3` only out of all those `SIZE1`, `SIZE2`, `SIZE3`, `SIZE4`, etc...

I simplified the situation enough, to actually be able to prepare a fiddle for you! So what I need to achieve is to include for each row of the `SELECT` query the appropriate `SIZE{\d}` field instead of the hardcoded `SIZE1` I used... From what I've read, the concept is called dynamic column, and needs a variable, and an `EXEC` command but my knowledge in SQL server is in its infancy so it's totally beyond me...

```
SELECT sub.ITEID, sub.SUBSTITUTECODE, prod.MAINSZLID, sub.SIZEPOS, siz.SIZE1
FROM @SUBSTITUTE AS sub
INNER JOIN @MATERIAL AS prod ON prod.ID = sub.ITEID
INNER JOIN @SIZELIST AS siz ON siz.CODEID = prod.MAINSZLID;
```

The fiddle can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0222d9720ed29ed37fa479c9212276ae)

Comment: This can be done with dynamic SQL (or maybe UNPIVOT) but the root cause of the complexity is the database model. A repeating column violates first normal form database design. It would be better to store the columns as rows separate rows.

Comment: I don't have control over the DB design. My task is only to create a bridge between this desktop app and an e-commerce website... Additionally, I know the concept that solves my problem is called dynamic columns... And that's all I know about it! Hehe! Could you provide me with some code i could use for my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..

```
CHOOSE(sub.sizepos, SIZE1, SIZE2, SIZE3, SIZE4, SIZE5, SIZE6, SIZE7, SIZE8, SIZE9, SIZE10, SIZE11, SIZE12, SIZE13, SIZE14, SIZE15, SIZE16, SIZE17, SIZE18, SIZE19, SIZE20, SIZE21, SIZE22, SIZE23, SIZE24, SIZE25)
```

…

Comment: Omg, I went through the documentation and it seems exactly what I need! Simple, yet effective. And because the data of the SIZE{d} fields is minimal, it won't have an impact on the performance either! And more importantly, it's compatible with SQL server 2014 that's running on the server! As soon as I return to the computer I'll try it and report back!

Comment: I just tried it and it works like a charm! Thank you SO very much! :D

Comment: .. @FayeD. .. 